# if else variable scope shows undefined in else in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am defining a variable named `htmlARR` in an `if/else` block. If I comment out the variable in the `else` block, it shows *undefined*, but if I don't comment it out, it shows the result.

**NOTE:** I can't the scope of variable come inside else also.

```
coffeeAllColGenHTML : function (allData, more) {
            console.log("WATER" + allData.WATER);
            console.log("providerWATER" + allData.PROVIDER_WATER);

            if (more) {
                var htmlArr = [];
                htmlArr.push(allData.COFFEE_DISH, "<br/><span class='sub-detail'>", allData.WATER, "</span>");
                return htmlArr.join("");
            } else {
/* this line */ //var htmlArr = [];
                htmlArr.push(allData.COFFEE_DISH, "<br/><span class='sub-detail'>", allData.PROVIDER_WATER, "</span>");
                return htmlArr.join("");
                //return allData.COFFEE_DISH;
                //console.log(allData.COFFEE_DISH);
            }
        },
```

Comment: It's because you define the variable inside your `if` statement. Move it out.

Comment: javascript does not have block scope, it has only global and function scopes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to scope your variable declaration:

```
coffeeAllColGenHTM: function (allData, more) {
        console.log("WATER" + allData.WATER);
        console.log("providerWATER" + allData.PROVIDER_WATER);
        var htmlArr = [];

        if (more) {
            htmlArr.push(allData.COFFEE_DISH, "<br/><span class='sub-detail'>", allData.WATER, "</span>");
            return htmlArr.join("");
        } else {
            htmlArr.push(allData.COFFEE_DISH, "<br/><span class='sub-detail'>", allData.PROVIDER_WATER, "</span>");
            return htmlArr.join("");
            //return allData.COFFEE_DISH;
            //console.log(allData.COFFEE_DISH);
        }
    },
```